# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen cuya ruta está guardada en SQL utilizando javascript y html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo una base de datos para una página web, que va almacenando información de unos formularios. En ese formulario hay una opción de adjuntar imágenes. Esas imágenes se guardan en una ruta *(PathDiagrama)*. Lo que yo quiero hacer es crear un botón para mostrar esas imágenes en una pestaña aparte, pero realmente no sé cómo. Las imágenes están en formato *jpg*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes mostrar lo que intentaste para que podamos corregir tu problema. Por otra parte, no es buena idea almacenar la ruta completa de las imágenes en ese formato porque cuando llegan a un navegador no se van a ver, pues no todos tenemos acceso a tu disco C:\ (solo los que te hayan puesto un troyano, je).  La ruta debería partir la raiz de tu web con una `/` en plan `/carpeta/imagenes/imagen.jpg` para que se pueda ver (y esas imágenes deben estar en tu carpeta `public//carpeta/imagenes/` (pongo public/ pero quizas la llamas de otro modo en tu servidor)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer un `src` con HTML

Primero tendrías que efectuar una consulta a la base de datos, por ejemplo, un archivo llamado `conexion.php`

```
   <?php 
         //Efectuando la conexion con MySQL
         $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","BaseDatos");
    ?>
```

Efectuas la consulta a tu base de datos

```
include 'conexion.php';
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombretabla WHERE ....";//Efectua la condicion necesaria
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
```

Después con HTML puedes mostrar la imagen, y al momento de colocar la ruta con `src` colocas lo que obtuviste de tu base de datos.

```
<img src="<?php $opciones['PathDiagrama'] ?>" height="55" width="55">
```

Si necesitas que se impriman todas, podrías usar un ciclo while, inténtalo y me cuentas